# logging website python brings up error -- Validation of the provided anti-forgery token failed

Tags: python, web, python-requests, antiforgerytoken

I am using Python to login to a website https://app.whiskeysystems.com/ and download certain files from it. However, I am getting the error

> The cookie __RequestVerificationToken and the form field
>   __RequestVerificationToken were swapped

I have tried providing the Antiforgery token, but still unable to understand what really is the problem.

Following is my current code (Python 2.7 on Windows 7, will also be using this code on MAC OS X):

```
import bs4

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

import requests 

import re 

import sys

import time

USER_AGENT = []


USER_AGENT.append('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36')

USER_AGENT.append('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36')

USER_AGENT.append('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.1 Safari/537.36')

USER_AGENT.append('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1')

basic_URL = "https://app.whiskeysystems.com/Account/Login/"

complete_URL = basic_URL

print("\n**** Starting Program **** ")

print ("\nThe user-agent selected ---> " + USER_AGENT[2])
print("\nChecking if website ---> " + basic_URL +"  is UP or DOWN ?")

with requests.Session() as client:

    client.headers.update({'User-Agent':USER_AGENT[2]})
    c2 = client.get(complete_URL)  

    print("\nHTTP Status Code ---> " + str(c2.status_code))


    if ( int(c2.status_code) == 200):
        print("\nSuccessful!!!. Website is UP")

        print ("\nWill try to login to website using provided credentials")

        time.sleep(2)

        csrftoken = client.cookies['__RequestVerificationToken']
        print("\nThe __RequestVerificationToken value ---> " + str(csrftoken))

        time.sleep(1)
        login_data = dict(__RequestVerificationToken=csrftoken,Email='abc@def.com', Password='123456') 
        r1 = client.post(complete_URL, data=login_data)
        print r1.text


    else:
        print("\n Error !!!. Quitting the program, please see the website is UP or not. ")
```

Comment: Please format your code, indentation is very important in python.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but its not the issue of indentation or syntax. the code runs successfully but it generates error when it POSTs the USERNAME + PASSWORD on the website.

Comment: No, i mean the code in your question. I can't read it like that.

Comment: oh sorry. let me repost

Comment: @t.m.adam i have re-formatted it. thanks.

Comment: The __RequestVerificationToken cookie is not the same as the __RequestVerificationToken input. You should get the token from `c2.text` with `bs4`.

Comment: @t.m.adam can you elaborate a more more c2.text ?

Comment: Yes, `csrftoken = BeautifulSoup(c2.text, 'html.parser').find('input', {'name':'__RequestVerificationToken'})['value']` all in one line.

Comment: @t.m.adam bingo, its working, thankyou so much.

Comment: but why is my methodology :
csrftoken = client.cookies['__RequestVerificationToken']

not working ?

ps: i have spent more than 3 days on this error. :-(

Comment: The cookie and form input may have the same name but they don't have the same value.

Comment: thanks sir, very much obliged by you.

Comment: Glad i could help:)